# Codeigniter run external PHP Script in a separated Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with Codeigniters Security.

My Codeigniter Installation has the `Application Folder, System Folder` and a `Assets Folder`.

In my Assets Folder there is a Third Party PHP Script.

I want to Call this Script: `DOMAIN/assets/FOLDEROFEXTERNALSCRIPT/EXTERNALPHPSCRIPT.php`

Is there a option that i can call this File over the URL without a Controller?

Comment: What happens when you try to access that script via a URL.  What errors do you get?

Comment: Why you are not accessing the file through url?

Comment: @Pattle
If I call the File I get a 404 Error. If I change my htaccess. I get an internal Server Error.
But the problem ist not my Script, I tested it with a easy echo script

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I hope you have removed index.php from your url's which is done by either adding the below rewrite rules in the .htaccess file at your DOMAIN root directory, or by adding these rewrite rules in the virtual hosts.

Below rule means, to rewrite every url to index.php?params except if the current url contains "index.php or assets in it", now you can put any static content or even core PHP scripts in this folder to be access directly, with having CI in picture.

In your .htaccess file just add "assets" folder in the bypass rule, along with index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^!(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hy, 
thanks.
This is currently my htaccess file: 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
  
  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

I have added your snippet to. But i get a 404 Error:

Comment: comment all the current rewrite rules that you are having and just put the above 3 lines. comment by just putting '#' in the starting of each line in your .htaccess file.

Comment: With this it works but i become a Internal Server Error. It's not a Script Problem I tested it with a easy echo script. <?php echo "Tralala" ?>
Do you know whats wrong`?

Thank you